# How do I know when an AVPlayer video has ended?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Scenario: iOS device automatically plays a video via AVPlayer upon entering an AVPlayerViewController.

How do I detect when the AVPlayer has finished?

Answer (score 1):

You can register to receive an `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` notification when a player item has completed playback.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: self.playerItem)
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Swift. Answers should be in Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: I've changed to a Swift example.

Comment: @bgilham I've tried this, running on iOS9 but my "playerItemDidReachEnd:"  function is not being called. Any suggestions ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone.
And I know its in Obj-C, but I had to add this to some old code ;)

```
- (void)setupVideo {

    NSString *stringVideoName = @"myVideo.mp4";
    NSString *stringVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:stringVideoName ofType:nil];

    NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringVideoPath];

    _playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlVideoFile];
    _playerViewController.view.frame = self.videoView.bounds;
    _playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

    // Identify when the player time position jumps.
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemTimeJumped:) name:AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification object:_playerViewController.player.currentItem];

    [self.videoView addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
    self.videoView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
}

- (void)playerItemTimeJumped:(NSNotification*)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = notification.object;

    if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification object:notification.object];
// The video play button has been pressed only once. Tell someone about it.
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, it does, :D Thanks. Though I don’t use full code, I've just used the notification part.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoDidEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
```